# If a Niddah spits on you are you Impure?

Tags: halacha, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, niddah, parashat-metzora

In [ויקרא טו](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0315.htm) it discusses Zav for a man, Niddah and Zavah.  There are some methods in which ritual impurity are transmitted which are listed for a Zav, but not for the other two, such as spitting.  According to [Ramban](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=3&perek=15&mefaresh=ramban), we learn that a Niddah and a Zavah must immerse from the case of the Zav, since it is not explicitly mentioned.  The underlying reason seems to be due to the similarity in transmission of impurity, so I'm wondering if all the methods for transmission of impurity listed for a Zav apply also to a Zavah and Niddah even though they're not listed, and why would some be listed and not others if they do apply?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zav, Niddah, Zavah and Yoledet all have the same rules regarding משקין היוצאין liquids which come out of them, namely saliva (including nasal mucus), urine and semen (which are Avot HaTumah) as well as tears, blood from a wound and breast-milk (which are Vladot HaTumah). See Rambam Mishkav UMoshav at the end of the first chapter ([15](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=10&hilchos=59&perek=1&halocha=15&hilite=) and [16](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=10&hilchos=59&perek=1&halocha=16&hilite=)).

Comment: I note menstrual blood is also an Av HaTumah but for a different reason.